# How to generate date time column values with time values for every minute interval in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, faker

I have now written this code to generate fake values for the columns. I want the datetime column with values like, for a particular day for every minute the data should be generated, so for one day (24 * 60) values should be there.
this is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import faker

# create some fake data
fake = Faker()

# function to create a dataframe with fake values for our workers
def make_workers(num):
    
    # lists to randomly assign to workers
    status_list = ['in', 'out']
    team_list = ['FL1_RM1','FL1_RM2','FL1_RM3', 'FL1_RM4', 'FL2_RM1']
    d1 = datetime.strptime(f'1/1/2022', '%m/%d/%Y')
    d2 = datetime.strptime(f'08/08/2022', '%m/%d/%Y')

    fake_workers = [{'ID':fake.random_number(digits=10),
                  'Temp':np.random.randint(low=35, high=50), 
                  'noted Date':fake.date_time_between(d1,d2),
                  'Status':np.random.choice(status_list), # assign items from list with different probabilities
                  'room_id':np.random.choice(team_list)} for x in range(num)]
        
    return fake_workers

worker_df = pd.DataFrame(make_workers(num=50000))
worker_df.head(20)
```

this will generate random time values for any particular date. Is there a way to generate date time values for every minute for each day.

Comment: Am I understanding correctly that this would render the parameter `num` unused and you would want to use the minutes between the two dates as `num` instead (i.e. a row for each minute)?

Comment: @MichaelHodel yes, i need a separate row for each minute

Comment: ok see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import faker

fake = Faker()

def make_workers():
    status_list = ['in', 'out']
    team_list = ['FL1_RM1','FL1_RM2','FL1_RM3', 'FL1_RM4', 'FL2_RM1']
    d1 = datetime.strptime(f'1/1/2022', '%m/%d/%Y')
    d2 = datetime.strptime(f'08/08/2022', '%m/%d/%Y')
    timestamps = pd.date_range(d1, d2, freq="1min")
    fake_workers = [{'ID':fake.random_number(digits=10),
                  'Temp':np.random.randint(low=35, high=50), 
                  'noted Date':timestamps[x],
                  'Status':np.random.choice(status_list),
                  'room_id':np.random.choice(team_list)} for x in range(len(timestamps))]
        
    return fake_workers

worker_df = pd.DataFrame(make_workers())
worker_df.head()
```

prints

| index | ID | Temp | noted Date | Status | room_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 4338085472 | 48 | 2022-01-01 00:00:00 | out | FL2_RM1 |
| 1 | 6228118896 | 35 | 2022-01-01 00:01:00 | out | FL2_RM1 |
| 2 | 3343476528 | 43 | 2022-01-01 00:02:00 | in | FL1_RM2 |
| 3 | 1990337765 | 48 | 2022-01-01 00:03:00 | in | FL1_RM1 |
| 4 | 8308542801 | 40 | 2022-01-01 00:04:00 | in | FL1_RM1 |